# 'raw_input' does nothing, regardless of the input given

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a tool that will encode/decode a string according to values in a dictionary however, I am stuck with the following code:

```
class edt():
    e_dic = {}

    def main(self):
        c = "hcqnxmytwukgirzoeaspdfvlbj"
        a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        e_dic = {}
        for i in range(len(c)):
            e_dic[a[i]] = c[i]
        e_dic[" "] = " "
        self.e_dic = e_dic
        e = edt()
        user_input = raw_input("1.Encode\n2.Decode\n")
        if user_input == "1":
            e.encode()
        elif user_input == "2":
            e.decode()
        else:
            False

    def encode(self):
        print("test")

    def decode(self):
        print("test")

def run():
    run_main = None
    run_main = edt()
    run_main.main()
```

I have omitted encode() and decode() as I don't think that they are causing the problem.
The problem is that this happens when I run it:

```
>>run()
1.Encode
2.Decode
>>
(The script pauses here to wait for the return key to be pressed, but does nothing regardless of the input given)
>>
```

I am given no error after this completes. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What if you type `1` and *then* press return?

Comment: The shell does nothing, it just waits for the next command to be entered

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What do `encode` and `decode` do? My guess: those function await another input, then do something to that, and return something, but you do nothing with whatever they return, like printing it or stuff.

Comment: Running your script as is does not give me any output.

Defining an entry point and replacing your Encode() and Decode() functions works as expected.

Comment: the encode() and decode() both print "test"

Comment: looks like the problem has been with using [learnstreet.com](https://www.learnstreet.com/scratchpad/python) for python interpreter, which does not seem to handle standard input very nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine. But shouldn't you be using an object to call the method? like so

```
class edt():
e_dic = {}

def encode(self):
    print "encoded "

def decode(self):
    print "decoded "

def main(self):
    c = "hcqnxmytwukgirzoeaspdfvlbj"
    a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    e_dic = {}
    for i in range(len(c)):
        e_dic[a[i]] = c[i]
    e_dic[" "] = " "
    self.e_dic = e_dic
    e = edt()
    user_input = raw_input("1.Encode\n2.Decode\n")
    if user_input == "1":
        e.encode()
    elif user_input == "2":
        e.decode()
    else:
        False

def run():
    run_main = None
    run_main = edt()
    run_main.main()
```

Output:

```
>>> run()
1.Encode
2.Decode
1
encoded
```

Fiddle here:

http://ideone.com/9eET4T

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives the same result in the shell. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I changed my code to this and it gave the same result listed in the question

Comment: Apologies, they were in my code but I forgot to add them in

Comment: @noogii2k I request you to please use ideone.com to run the code. Add a run() at the end of the code and your choice in the stdin and you will get your desired output. Or check mine here http://ideone.com/9eET4T

Comment: Thanks, it seems my problem is with my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `self`  in encode and decode.

```
class edt(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.e_dic = {}
    def main(self):
        c = "hcqnxmytwukgirzoeaspdfvlbj"
        a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        for i in range(len(c)):
            self.e_dic[a[i]] = c[i]
        self.e_dic[" "] = " "
        user_input = raw_input("1.Encode\n2.Decode\n")
        if user_input == "1":
            self.encode()
        elif user_input == "2":
            self.decode()
        else:
            return False

    def encode(self):
        print("test")

    def decode(self):
        print("test")
def run():
    run_main = None
    run_main = edt()
    run_main.main()
run()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same problem

Comment: where are you running it from and are you using the code exactly as posted?

Comment: I'm running it from a shell on my computer and on [this website](https://www.learnstreet.com/scratchpad/python)

Comment: @noogii2k, I changed some of your code, you don't need to create instances inside your class to access the class methods, that is what self is for.